# Proving that a set is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I am trying to show the following proposition:

> **Proposition.** In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the set $A = \{(x,1/x) \in \mathbb{R}^2\}$ is closed.

I can think of two ways to do this. One is to take an arbitrary convergent sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ and prove that its limit is an element of $A$. Another is to consider its complement and prove that it's open. I can't figure out how to do the former, so I opted for the latter. We have $A^c = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y \neq 1/x\}$. I'm not able to visualize this set, however, so I can't figure out how to show that it's open. I can take an arbitrary element $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, and need to show there exists an open ball around it that's entirely contained in $A^c$. By excluding $(x,1/x)$ for each $x$, I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: If you know the topological defenition of continuous map, this can be very easy question.

Comment: $\{(x,1/x) \in \Bbb{R}^2\}$ is the graph of the function $y(x) = 1/x$.  Its complement is the plane with that graph deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R^2&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&(x,y)&\mapsto&xy.\end{array}$$Then $A=f^{-1}\bigl(\{1\}\bigr)$ and so, since $f$ is continuous and $\{1\}$ is closed, $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily prove that $A:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y\neq 1/x\}$ is open:

For a given $(x,y) \in A$, let $d:=|y-1/x|$, then the ball of center $(x,y)$ and radius $\frac{d}{2}$ in contained within $A$

Comment: I'm having trouble showing that $B_{d/2} ((x,y)) \subset A$. If I take $(x', y') \in B_{d/2} (x,y)$, then $|(x', y') - (x,y)| < \frac{d}{2} < \frac{|y-1/x|}{2}$. How does this imply that $(x', y') \in A$?

Comment: @JohnT Sure! Just show that $|y'-\frac{1}{x'}| < \frac{d}{2}$

Comment: I'm still struggling still. The above statement reduces to $|(x' - x) + (y' - y)| < \frac{d}{2}$. I can't use the triangle inequality on the left-hand side, but I can use the "reverse" triangle inequality, which allows me to focus on just a single component. Is that the way to go about this?

Comment: @JohnT I haven't really tried but shouldn't it be easy to show that $|y-y'|<\frac{d}{2}$ and $|x-x'|<\frac{d}{2}$